# Laravel: Routing & Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

I'm a beginner using this laravel framework. Currently i'm trying to understand the routing and controller of this framework.

I created a controller file using this command:

```
php artisan make:controller Admin/PostController
```

Of course the output of this is to create a controller file inside Admin folder. Inside of the PostController.php i wrote a code like this:

```
    public function create()
    {
      return view('admin.post.post');
    }
```

Also, in my web.php i have this code.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('user.blog');
});

Route::get('posts',function(){
return view('user.posts');
})->name('posts');


Route::resource('admin/post','Admin\PostController');
```

The "admin" is a folder and the "post" is a folder too inside the "admin" and when you open the "post" folder you'll see the "post.blade.php" file. The other two route::get in my web.php are working fine. But the route:resource is not working.

When i tried to run this in my browser using this link:

```
localhost:8000/admin/post/create
```

The browser says: **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found**

Is there any problem with syntax or path structures?

Here's my post.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')


@section('main-content')
 this is just html codes..
 @endsection
```

Here's my php artisan route:list
[image: route list]

Comment: localhost:8000/admin/post/create it is a post request? is'nt it ?

Comment: I'm trying to follow this tutorial but it seems not working. I double checked my code but i dont see any flaws. @Salman Zafar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMYSpg93wYU&index=8&list=PLe30vg_FG4OTELVqQgHaMaq2oELjpSWy_

Comment: can you post your blade file code as well

Comment: localhost:8000/admin/post/create when you hit this link. The browser should redirect me to the post.blade.php because i already stated in my code in PostController.php the "return view('admin.post.post');"

Comment: php artisan route:list post the output in your question

Comment: I updated my post. Included the route list and codes for post.blade.php

Comment: in your blade file after this <form role="form"> add this line @csrf and then try again

Comment: hi,
put Route::get('posts/create', function () {
return view('admin.post.post');
}); above route:resource line and go to localhost:8000/posts/create and tell us what happens

Comment: Late reply sir, hello @ashish it works!! thankyou! but whats the meaning of this code sir? is this connected too to my PostController.php file ?

Comment: It is not connected to your post controller file, i was trying to check if your view accessible or not. seems to be, there is some conflict on your route:resource

Comment: I think so.. But the only code added to my PostController only this: return view('admin.post.post'); inside the public function create. i'm sill trying to figure it out why the route::resource is not working

Comment: i think you should try and see if the same code works if you arent using admin in Route::resource('admin/post','Admin\PostController'); see this works when you do administrator instead

Comment: i tested this codeRoute::resource('admin/post','Admin\PostController'); but this code isn't working as it connected to my PostController. But the one code you gave to me is working fine.

Comment: The code i gave you before isnt using postcontroller at all. If you want to use PostController, you have to find a day to do it. BTW, i have tested your code in my computer and its working in my end.

Comment: I want to use postcontroller. If my code is working on your computer maybe the version of my laravel is the reason why not working here? Because there are times like i was trying to run my laravel using this code. php artisan serve  but this code is not working on my computer but i tried this php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ it works

Answer (score 0):

this because some time composer stuck, for that times you should stop serve and re generate autoload

1.stop your php artisan serve
2.enter this command

```
composer dumpautoload
```

3.run your php artisan serve